# Why to use ValueAccessor's in Angular?

Tags: angular

As we know, all `ValueAccessors` (I mean: `NumberValueAccessor`, `RangeValueAccessor`, etc...) are interfaces which are 'proxy' between native input and Angular `FormControl`.

**But what is the purpose of use it?** 
It is not simpler (and better) to call `.valueChanges` on `FormControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume I am interested in making reusable colour picker component like this.

[image: Color picker component with variable opacity]

#### Inside this component

You should implement [**ControlValueAccessor**](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface because you get access to a lot of functions.

1. writeValue
2. registerOnChange
3. registerOnTouched
4. setDisabledState

With the help of these functions you could manage the state/value of the control object. By doing so, any component can give a **`[formControl]`** as input to this colour picker component and colour picker can update its value with the help of these functions, it can set its state to touched or untouched, it can set it's validity to valid/invalid. Basically you get full control inside colour picker component over the control object, you do what you need to and when you need to.

Now on the other hand, other components using this component can listen to value changes using **`valueChanges`**, listen for status changes using **`statusChanges`** etc.

---

You could use **valueChanges** when you are only interested in listening changes because while listening you could not update the value of control (because it will go in infinite loop, you will change the value and again valueChanges subscription would fire again.)

---

#### TLDR;

They both are different things, have different use cases. One is an interface which a class has to implement while other one is a stream of changed values that any component can listen inside a function. It would not be good to compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

Say you wanted to create a specialised timepicker component.

By implementing ControlValueAccessor* you have a component that can directly plug into reactive / template forms. The timepicker component internally handles how changes to the clock hand translates to a time and vice versa.

> ***ControlValueAccessor** - defines an interface that acts as a bridge between the Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM

`.valueChanges` is an Observable that emits every time the value of the control changes. How would you translate an movement of a clock hand into a formControl value change? setValue? Good luck with that.